# Mesh intersecting due to Weight Painting probably

Tags: weight-painting

I have Dog Mesh and Jersey on top of it. I transfered weight from dog to jersey via Data Transfer. It did solid job, but now after animating it I noticed this problem. I don't know if I get it then or afterwards, since I did some aditional Weight painting on Dog Mesh. I tried to aditionaly weight paint it again but didn't get satisfying results. And if I try to Data Transfer painting from Dog again, it gets even worse.
[image][image]

Comment: Did you normalize your weigth painting?

Comment: I tried but doesn't get any better.